# react-hook-form Controller with react-draft-wysiwyg

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-draft-wysiwyg

I need some help. I was using react-final-form in my project but I've decided to change for react-hook-form. By the way, I love it, but I got stuck. :/

On my page, I'm using an editor to collect some info from a user. At the moment I'm using react-draft-wysiwyg.
Here the code:

**parentComponent.js**

```
/**
 * react-hook-form library
*/
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    control
} = useForm({
    mode: 'onChange'
});

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <Controller
        as={<WYSIWYGEditor />}
        name='editor'
        control={control}
        onChange={([ event ]) => event.target.value}
    />
</form>
```

**WYSIWYGEditor.js**

```
const WYSIWYGEditor = ({ input }) => {
    const [ editorState, setEditorState ] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());
    const onEditorStateChange = editorState => {
        setEditorState(editorState);
    };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <Editor
                    editorState={editorState}
                    wrapperClassName='wrapper-class'
                    editorClassName='editor-class'
                    onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
                />
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default WYSIWYGEditor;
```

***PLEASE NOTE:*** 
The input prop comes from the coding with react-final-form.  The input was passing the characters I was typing. So, if I leave `input` as props it fails because it doesn't exist. React-hook-form doesn't pass an input. 
I've changed that with `props`:

```
const WYSIWYGEditor = props=> {
    console.log(props)
```

and I get the following in the console.log when I type anything:

```
{name: "editor", value: undefined, onChange: ƒ}
```

As you can see, value is `undefined`. How can I structure the `Controller` in order to pass a value each time I type something in the editor?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution.

`value` is undefined because obviously on component load there is nothin' to load. If you don't want to see `undefined` just pass `defaultValue=''` from the controller:

```
<Controller
  as={<WYSIWYGEditor />}
  name='editor'
  control={control}
  onChange={([ event ]) => event.target.value}
  defaultValue='' <== here
/>
```

Now, the issue that doesn't allow to return any typed value, is because I have declared the onChange from the controller. So, the right code would be:

```
<Controller
  as={<WYSIWYGEditor />}
  name='editor'
  control={control}
  defaultValue=''
/>
```

Also, in the `WYSIWYGEditor.js` file, you need to replace what before was `input` with `props`. The reason is that they are passing exactly the same Object, which contains a `value`, `onChange`, and `onBlur` function.

Here a code sandbox with the working code: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-mountain-k24ys?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing this solution. It was super helpful for getting me unstuck! react-hook-form's `Controller` prop interface seems to have changed a bit since you wrote this, but it was no problem to figure out with this as a starting point. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package "react-draft-wysiwyg-input"
It have been working as html input

```
import { RichTextInput } from '@tonz/react-draft-wysiwyg-input';
import '@tonz/react-draft-wysiwyg-input/style.css';

<div className="mb-6">
  <Label className="block mb-2 ">Desc</Label>
  <RichTextInput disabled={disabled} {...register('desc')} />
  {errors.desc && <ErrorHint data-testid="confirmPasswordError">{errors.desc.message}</ErrorHint>}
</div>
```